# Converting boolean frame to factors in R

Tags: r

[dataframe with 22 variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kowH3.png)

Hi there, new guy on the site. :) How do I convert these 22 variables into 5 explanatory variables with levels instead of the current boolean using Rstudio? I’ve tried a few different approaches, but I cannot get it to work properly.

Comment: Not clear about what you wanted.  it is better to show a small example along with expected output instead of images

Comment: fx, the BuyingPrice columns I would like to combine into a single column so I get a factor BuyingPrice: low (1), medium (2), high (4), and very high (5) to perform a log reg on the data to predict the Evaluation (acceptable or unacceptable) of the car based on 5 explanatory variables.

Comment: please see this post on how to post a reproducible question in r https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO! have you tried `as.factor`?

```
> as.factor(c(1,0))
[1] 1 0
Levels: 0 1
```

Say you want to convert columns 2:6 in your `df` then:

```
df[,2:6] <- as.factor(df[,2:6])
```